# Joomla 1.5.24 Plugin ratings

Tags: plugins, joomla

My question is Does Joomla plugin ratings matter? If so, how to know which one should be the first, the second and so on? Or where to find that kind of information?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean: "plugin ratings" ? maybe the order ?

Comment: @Shaz Yes, the order of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

In general: YES. It matters.

The only example (and probably the easiest one) I can give you at this moment is: Cache plugins (system type). They should be at the end of the list (higher number) to ensure you are caching the "final result" of a page (as far as I know).

Most extensions will put themselves on the "right" place in the list when they are installed. However if you have a lot of plugins, the oldest installed plugins might be misplaced.

Here is a small article about it:

http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla-Tips-Techniques/Ordering-of-Joomla-plugins.php

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand how plugins work. but still it doesn't really help me to solve problem I have with Joomla...

Comment: Your question doesn't include any problem, you are only asking how plugins order work.